# Under MongoDB java driver Mapreduce command scope; add functions to Scope

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Is their a way to Execute a MongoDB map reduce job through the java driver in which you create a scope DBObject that contains functions.

I can execute my map reduce configuration in javascript where the passed in scope contains utility functions, but I can't figure out how to do this with the java driver.

I setup the scope using mapReduceCommand's

`c.addExtraOption("scope",new BasicDBObject().append('average',function(){ return false;}));`

However I can't get the mappers/reducers to recognize the scope component 'e.g.' average as a function. If I use quotes, the map reduce context thinks its a String, but if not, I can't seem to make the scope component parse.

How does one get a function in the scope component through the java driver?

> Thanks to Ren's answer, Here is a spring bean configuration to set up a scope for the mongodb java driver with a function.

```
    <util:map id="mrScope" 
              key-type="java.lang.String" 
              value-type="java.lang.Object">
    <entry key="buckets"><bean class="com.mongodb.util.JSON" factory-method="parse"><constructor-arg value="[0,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65]"/></bean></entry>
    <entry key="average">
        <bean class="org.bson.types.CodeWScope">
            <constructor-arg value="function () {var s = 0;for (var i = 0; i &gt; arguments.length; i++) s += arguments[i];return s / arguments.length;}"/>
            <constructor-arg><bean class="org.bson.BasicBSONObject"/></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </entry>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details like how to use a Map as scope object.. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The server code automatically converts the map and reduce into Javascript function, but not so with scope. To pass a function in the scope option, you can do this instead:

```
c.addExtraOption("scope", new BasicBSONObject("average",
  new CodeWScope("function(){ return false;}", new BasicBSONObject())));
```

Comment: Thanks Ren. This part of Mongo is not as well documented as some would like :) So it is good to find the answers.

Answer (score 1):

With the new api (3.0).. I found the below option is working

`collection
    .mapReduce(map, reduce)
    .scope(new Document("key", value))
    .limit(100);`

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggle with applying function in scope using MongoTemplate, example below seems to work:

```
    Map<String, Object> scopeVariables = new HashMap<>();
    String scopeFunction="function(){ //do something }";
    scopeVariables.put("transform", new CodeWScope(scopeFunction,new BasicBSONObject()));

    MapReduceOptions options = new MapReduceOptions();
    options.scopeVariables(scopeVariables);
    options.outputTypeInline();

    MapReduceResults<ValueObject> result = template.mapReduce("collection", mapFunction, reduceFunction, options, ValueObject.class);
```

After running code above, transform() function will be visible in map function:

```
var mapFunction=function(){  
  transform(); 
  emit(key,value); 
}
```