# Java - Storing a string in Mongo as a object without any type

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have

```
String  toInsert = "somestring";

insert(toInsert);
```

and

```
insert(String toInsert) {

     DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();

     dbo.put("value" : toInsert);
}
```

In Mongo, this is saved as

```
{"value" : "somestring"}
```

But I would like it to be saved as

```
{"value" : somestring}
```

How can I change this to be saved it Mongo like this?

The 'somestring' I am trying to insert is a Javascript Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a CodeWScope object by passing the string that contains the javascript method to the constructor. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037569/under-mongodb-java-driver-mapreduce-command-scope-add-functions-to-scope/10045887#10045887) for an example on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the function name as a string, then when you want to actually run the function you can use reflection to load the method and run it.

See: [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string) for how.

Edit: I may have misinterpreted the question, did you mean that "somestring" in your example is the name of a *Java* function, or did you mean that it is an actual *Javascript* function? If the latter is the case, then there's no reason not to store it as a string, and more context is needed to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was trying to do the latter - inserting a javascript function